# How to check if branch diverged with php?

Tags: php, git

Now i have just one poor idea : use `git status` and then parse with Regex word `diverged`.

Note: Seems it not work if i try checkout, for example, from master to diverged branch bc git status say all is ok with master.

Answer (score 0):

Use a php git library?

Like Git.php https://github.com/kbjr/Git.php

Comment: And how i can check with this library if branch which i want to checkout is diverged?